# Unexpected EOF while parsing Syntax Error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, syntax-error, eof

I just started using Python's `keyboard` module. I was exploring with the code below until there was a error occurring at the end on line 5. The goal of the code below is to detect if I pressed the "a" on my keyboard. I attempted to put a semicolon at the end of the print function, and I tried to replace the `print("A")`  with `pass` and `break` but Python gave me the same error as before.

```
import keyboard
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            print("A")
```

Output:

```
File "c:\users\emma\mu_code\keyboard.py", line 6

Syntax Error: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Why do I have this syntax error and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code add the **except** block, like so:

```
import keyboard
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            print("A")
   except:
      #do something else, if there is an error, or any other key is pressed
```

If u dont know if u need try except, then just dont keep it in the try block:

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            print("A")
```

Comment: See also: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: I tried that https://replit.com/@EmmaGao8/Keyboard-Sensor#main.py but nothing happens if I press the q key.

Comment: Ok i will try it on replit later, but try to install python in ur pc, and then see if it works

Comment: I already installed Python, but if I try there, they say that keyboard isn't defined, so I just use replit.com

Comment: **pip install keyboard** in command prompt as keyboard doesnt come pre installed, it happened to me too

Comment: I didn't install pip and I don't know how to.

Comment: Also see: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/ also try typing **python get-pip.py** in command line. Alright i think the conversation is growing too long

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add except part.
If you are using try/except statement you need an except statement.

Make it.

```py
import keyboard
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            print("A")
    else:
       # Rest code . If you don't want to do anything then simply pass
       pass
```